# Vuetify v-data-table align center only one column

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-data-table

i have:

```
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="tableData" :items-per-page="5" class="elevation-1">

        <template v-slot:item.id="{ item }">
            {{item.id}}
        </template>
```

How can I align the content of that column vertically center?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify the alignment of each column setting `align` equal to `center` in your `headers` definition. E.g.:

```js
headers: [
  {
    text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
    align: 'center',
    sortable: false,
    value: 'name',
  },
  { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
  { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
  { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
  { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
  { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
],
```

If that doesn't work in your configuration, try also removing the slot template.

Answer (score 10):

Try to wrap that content by a `div` with class name `d-flex justify-center` as follows :

```
<template v-slot:item.id="{ item }">
            <div class="d-flex justify-center">{{item.id}}</div>
        </template>
```